# problem in comparing string to a integer i guess

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, c-strings, digits

This code is not working, how many times the number 0 to 9 is repeated in a given string.

This is the question, itis from hackerrank:

> Given a string, S, consisting of alphabets and digits, find the frequency of each digit in the given string.

I can't find any error in my logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    char s[1000];
    int count[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    char temp;
    scanf("%s", s);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        temp = i;

        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(s); j++)
        {
            if (s[j] == i)
            {
                count[i] = count[i] + 1;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        printf("%d ", count[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried tracing the execution with a debugger, to where it behaves differently than you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you need to write

```
if (s[j] == i + '0')
```

Otherwise you are trying to compare a character like `'0'` that can have the ASCII code `48` with integer `0`.

But in any case the for loops are inefficient.

It is better to write:

```
for (const char *p = s; *p; ++p)
{
    if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9') ++count[*p - '0'];
}
```

Comment: why is it inefficient? i dont have much knowledge about this. i'm still learning.

Comment: @TusharKamboj At least because the same string is parsed 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a character to an integer. Now, `char` is a numeric type, so you can do this, but the results are not what you expect. The character `'0'` in ASCII is `48`, for example.

You can convert `0` or `1` or any other single digit to its ASCII representation, by adding it to `'0'`.

Answer (score -1):

`if (s[j] == i)` => here `s` is defined as a character and `i` is defined as an integer. So to solve this problem you have to convert your integer to a character. sprintf() could work or a simple +'0'.

Comment: Actually, `s` is a char array. `s[j]` is a `char`.

Comment: `char` can be compared with `int` without issue (even if the `int` has a larger value than `char` can hold). There's nothing inherently wrong with comparing `int` and `char` as long as you account for the fact that the ASCII character has a particular integer value that may be different than you expect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).